# post request and get xml response

Tags: php, curl

Code:

```
$url = 'example/'.$reqID.'/';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
      //var_dump($output);
curl_close($ch);
```

Error:

> curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: Invalid curl configuration option

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: this error generate "curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: Invalid curl configuration option"

Comment: you have not set the url in curl

Comment: i set url correctly. i didn't put here.

Comment: where is your url in `curl_setopt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error can indicate that you try to use `curl` in an `IPv6` enabled environment and don't tell `curl` to resolve over `IPv4`

try to set the option

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);`

> Allows an application to select what kind of IP addresses to use when
>   resolving host names. This is only interesting when using host names
>   that resolve addresses using more than one version of IP, possible
>   values are CURL_IPRESOLVE_WHATEVER, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4,
>   CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6, by default CURL_IPRESOLVE_WHATEVER.